# Is it possible to browse files from HDD containing OS esxi?

Tags: vmware-esxi, hard-drive, filesystems

my office have a broken esxi server that suddenly doesn't want to boot up. I am suspecting it is caused by motherboard.

I am trying to access the server's Hard drive to get some VM files inside the hard drive.

I tested to browse the hard drive using an external hdd enclosure 2.5 and some software listed here : https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/browse-linux-partition-windows/ to access it from windows 10.
But I cannot browse / open the hard drive.

Is it possible to access the hard drive (read) and copy some files out?
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

ESXi uses it's own filesystem, VMFS. As far as I know it's not possible to mount this under Windows. You can however mount it unter linux (read only) using the `vmfs-tools` package, which is available on the major distributions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I will try mount it using `vmfs-tools` under linux then.
I will try to follow this article http://woshub.com/how-to-access-vmfs-datastore-from-linux-windows/ and post the result!